# How to import Lit runtime only once and not for all components

Tags: lit-html, tree-shaking, lit

I am developing a component library in Lit (https://lit.dev) and I am wondering how to avoid bundling the full lit runtime for each component.

Any hint?

Comment: What do you mean by "lit runtime"? Lit doesn't have a runtime.

Comment: Lit weights 5kb, does this mean that every single component I will made will start from 5kb? Or I can "use" the 5kb of Lit once and share it among the components?

Comment: This is done automatically by the build tools. If you import component A in your project and it uses lit version 1.0.0 and you also import component B in your project and it also uses lit version 1.0.2 . Your build tool will only bundle a single instance of lit version 1.0.2.